# libgdx : Scrolling background from spritesheet causes lag when sprite is repositioned... am I doing something wrong?

Tags: sprites, libgdx, parallax-scrolling, scrolling

So, I use a sprite from a spritesheet to draw the background and repeat it. (I am drawing it twice) However, the moment that the background is re-positioned to make it look infinite, it causes a lag.

What's the right way to do this without having the background image in a separate file?

```
BetterSprite sprite = new BetterSprite(new TextureRegion(sprites_texture), spritedef.x, spritedef.y, spritedef.width, spritedef.height);

// BetterSprite is just my extended class that returns .scaledWidth and scaledHeight for scaled sprites
```

this is how I draw the background

```
    //initial scrollingX = 0

    floor.setScale(textureScale);
    floor.setY(0);
    floor.setX(scrollingX);
    floor.draw(batch);

    // fill screen
    floor.setX(scrollingX + floor.getScaledWidth());
    floor.draw(batch);

    //fill screen
    floor.setX(scrollingX + ( floor.getScaledWidth() *2) );
    floor.draw(batch);

    if(scrollingX < -floor.getScaledWidth() ){
        scrollingX += floor.getScaledWidth();
    }
```

The 'scrollingX' gets updated in the doUpdate() method.

It's pretty good when scrolling, but when scrollingx<-floor.getScaledWidth() happens, I get lag.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Comment: @anko it's about "what is the correct way to do this?" like what's the correct way to scroll/loop a sprite without causing lag